# OpenFaaS faasd function deployed but the URL fails with the message "cannot find service"

Tags: kubernetes, clojure, openfaas

I followed this tutorial for faasd. https://github.com/openfaas/faasd/blob/master/docs/MULTIPASS.md

I was able to deploy my function in Clojure successfully, but the URL returned shows the message of

```
Cannot find service: mybot.openfaas-fn.
```

And when I tried the URL without .openfaas-fn extension, it just fails to load showing

```
This page isn’t working 
192.168.64.3 is currently unable to handle this request. 
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I wonder if there's anyway to debug this. I tried `faas-cli describe mybot`

```
Name: mybot
Status: Ready
Replicas: 1
Available replicas: 1
Invocations: 7
Image:
Function process:
URL: http://192.168.64.3:8080/function/mybot
Async URL: http://192.168.64.3:8080/async-function/mybot
```

Actually, I tried to deploy with Kubernetes before, but that didn't work out either. Functions can be deployed and work for a few minutes then get into CrashLoopBackOff, stopped working and the page would keep loading forever.

How can I possibly solve this or would there be any alternatives for deployment? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your clojure function do?

Comment: @JaredSmith It's a parser that extracts nested JSON data from newsapi and reshapes it into the format I want. I am hoping to use OpenFaas then generate an url for the parsed data.

Comment: It's worth noting that I was able to do a `faas-cli build` and a `faas-cli deploy` without ever doing a `faas-cli push`. I don't *think* that is the same issue you were having, but it allowed me to deploy a "function" that didn't have a usable container for execution. I made sure to either download a local docker registry and set the image in the .yml to point there or push to my docker hub account. Then use `faas-cli up -f ./config.yml` to set up the function. The local docker registry can be deployed using `docker run -d --restart always -p5000:5000 registry:latest`. This is for testing...